# Background image not viisible in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im  trying to create a window with a background image,but when i set this.Resizeble() to false the background is not visible

this is he code is tried.if the line this.setResizable(false) is turned to a comment this code works,
but i dont want to change the window size as the contents get displaced.so i tried to set it to non resizabele but then the background image is not visible.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.Exception;

 class mainwindow extends JFrame{

    mainwindow(){
        this.setSize(600,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        JLabel jbl,background;
        jbl=new JLabel("MAIN",JLabel.CENTER);
        jbl.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        jbl.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,20));
        this.add(jbl);
        
        
        
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("/home/user/Desktop/codes/project/background.jpg"); 
        Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); 
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); 
        
        ImageIcon img=new ImageIcon(newimg);
        background=new  JLabel(img);
        background.setBounds(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());
        background.setIcon(img);
        add(background);
        
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}

public class newproject{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    new mainwindow();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1 - calls to swing methods should be executed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT), unless the documentation says differently - see [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading); 2 - try making the frame visible as last statement

Comment: You code is working fine. The path to the image is wrong. You need to adapt it

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)